# Replace Instances of Character " * " With Elements in Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, ecmascript-6

I know that I'm going to need a blank, empty array, and push characters from the sentence into the array if they aren't asterisks.

I think this will help me understand what to do once I actually want to iterate through the items in the array and use them as the replacements.

```
function replaceAsterisk(sentence, newWords) {

  let newArray = [];

  let character = sentence.split("");

  console.log(character);

  // if the character is not an asterisk, push it into the new array
  if (character !== "*") {
    newArray.push(character);
  }

  // if the character is an asterisk, push "cat" into the new array
  else {
    newArray.push("cat");
  }
  // return new array as a string
  return newArray.join(" ");
}

console.log(replaceAsterisk("My name is * and I am a *.", ["Sabrina", "Black Cat", "extra", "words"]));
```

Even now, this is not pushing "cat" into the array - why?

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? Are you not allowed to use built-in replacement functions?

Comment: Also, what result did you get from that code?

Comment: `character instanceof Array`.

Comment: Note `character` variable will be an `array` after `split()`, and then `character !== "*"` will always be true. Rare you don't see that in your console...

Comment: I can't use `return sentence.replace(/"*"/g, "cat")` because I will want to replace the asterisks with "Sabrina", "Black Cat", "extra", and "words".

Comment: You have quotes in there. Remove them. `/\*/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.replace()`](http://counter) with a function that generates the replacement string. In the function get the current replacement from `newWords` using a counter:

```js
function replaceAsterisk(sentence, newWords) {
  let counter = 0;
  
  return sentence.replace(/\*/g, () => newWords[counter++] || '');
}

console.log(replaceAsterisk("My name is * and I am a *.", ["Sabrina", "Black Cat", "extra", "words"]));
```

Comment: I really like this idea of using a counter - that makes sense. But what is `c =>` ? Where did that come from?

Comment: This is an ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Sure but the `c` - c is not declared as a variable earlier? Or should it be `counter`?

Comment: It's a standard callback function. You can write it as `function() { return newWords[counter++] || ''; }`.

Comment: I think like you, string.replace should be alway better than using string.split and blah blah blah

Comment: And you don't actually need `c`.

Comment: `() => newWords[counter++] || '*'`... ?

Comment: `() => newWords[counter++] || ''` - return the word found at counter, increment the count. If newWords[counter] is `undefined` return an empty string (the `'*' is your typo).

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through all the characters first, see below the example.

```js
function replaceAsterisk(sentence, newWords) {

  let newArray = [];

  let character = sentence.split("");

  console.log(character);
  
  character.forEach(function(c){
    // if the character is not an asterisk, push it into the new array
    if (c !== "*") {
      newArray.push(c);
    }

    // if the character is an asterisk, push "cat" into the new array
    else {
      newArray.push("cat");
    }
  });
  // return new array as a string
  return newArray.join("");
}

console.log(replaceAsterisk("My name is * and I am a *.", ["Sabrina", "Black Cat", "extra", "words"]));
```

Comment: You missed the unnecessary space that is used in `newArray.join(" ");`. It is not required, the string can just be joined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all of the characters in the sentence:

```js
function replaceAsterisk(sentence, newWords) {
  let newArray = [];

  for( let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) { // This line
    character = sentence[i];
    // if the character is not an asterisk, push it into the new array
    if (character !== "*") {
      newArray.push(character);
    }
  
    // if the character is an asterisk, push "cat" into the new array
    else {
      newArray.push("cat");
    }
  }
  // return new array as a string
  return newArray.join(" ");
}

console.log(replaceAsterisk("My name is * and I am a *.", ["Sabrina", "Black Cat", "extra", "words"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works. Splitting on empty strings can be weird (See [MDN...split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Syntax))

```js
  let newArray = [], sentence = "My name is * and I am a *.";      
  for (let char of sentence){ newArray.push(char); }
  for(let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
    if(newArray[i] == "*"){ newArray[i] = "cat"; }
  }
  console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex group match and `Array.prototype.shift`

```js
replaceAsterisk = (text, words) => {
  const _words = words.slice();
  return text.replace(/(\*)/g, (match) => _words.shift() || match);
}

// valid input
const output1 = replaceAsterisk("My name is * and I am a *.", ["Sabrina", "Black Cat", "extra", "words"]);
console.log(output1);
// empty input
const output2 = replaceAsterisk("My name is * and I am a *.", []);
console.log(output2);
```

Comment: Most simple answer - I like this one. So this arrow function basically takes the place of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each of the characters in the sentence, and get the word to replace with using `shift`:

```js
function replaceAsterisk(sentence, newWords) {
  let newStr = "";
  [...sentence].forEach(char => {
    if (char != "*") {
      newStr += char;
    } else {
      newStr += newWords.shift();
    }
  });
  return newStr;
}

console.log(replaceAsterisk("My name is * and I am a *.", ["Sabrina", "Black Cat", "extra", "words"]));
```